# OCaml strange behavior in pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I am trying to implement a queue structure in OCaml, and now writing a function that tests whether a value is in the queue.  I originally wrote a correct--or at least I think it was a correct--implementation of the function.  But when I tested it, I would get unexpected test failures.  Namely, it would return false when the queue was empty (a good thing) but would also return false in every other cases, whether the queue was empty or not, and whether the queue contained the value or not.  So I re-wrote the function in this kind of dumb way (where `Some h -> true`) in order to try to figure out what the problem is.  Even with this dumb function, it's still returning false when I pass it any queue and any value, so clearly it's reading the head of every queue as a `None`, whether it is a `None` or not.

**Contains:**

```
let contains (v: 'a) (q: 'a queue) : bool =
    if not (valid q) then failwith "contains: given invalid queue";
    let rec loop (value: 'a) (qn: 'a qnode option) : bool =
      begin match qn with
      | None -> false
      | Some h -> true
      end
    in loop elt q.head
```

**Tests**

```
   let test () : bool =
    let q = create () in
    not (contains 1 q)
  ;; run_test "contains empty" test

  let test () : bool =
    let q = from_list [2; 3] in
    contains 3 q
  ;; run_test "contains non-empty true" test

  let test () : bool =
    let q = from_list [2; 3] in
    not (contains 4 q)
  ;; run_test "contains non-empty false" test
```

The other functions written here have been tested and come out as expected.  The type declaration for the queue type is

```
  type 'a qnode = { v: 'a;
                    mutable next: 'a qnode option }

  type 'a queue = { mutable head: 'a qnode option;
                     mutable tail: 'a qnode option }
```

Any thoughts about why it's taking every `q.head` to be `None` would be appreciated.

---

**from_list**

A helper function that walks through a list turning each value into a qnode and linking it to the next, returning the resulting list.

```
  let rec vals_to_qnodes (l: 'a list) : 'a qnode list =
    begin match l with
    | [] -> []
    | [h] -> [{v = h; next = None}]
    | h1::h2::t -> let sofar = vals_to_qnodes (h2::t) in
                    begin match sofar with
                    | [] -> []
                    | x::y -> {v = h1; next = Some x}::x::y
                    end
    end
```

Make the list of qnodes, find its first and last elements, and assign them as the head and tail of the queue.

```
  let from_list (l: 'a list) : 'a queue =
    let qsList = vals_to_qnodes l in
    begin match qsList with
    | [] -> create ()
    | h::t -> begin match t with
              | [] -> {head = Some h; tail = Some h}
              | h2::t2 -> let x = List.rev t2 in
                          begin match x with
                          | [] -> {head = None; tail = None;}
                          | h3::t3 -> {head = Some h; tail = Some h3}
                          end
              end
    end
```

---

Here's what I originally had for the contains function before I tried to simplify it to narrow in on the strange behavior.

```
let contains (v: 'a) (q: 'a queue) : bool = 
  if not (valid q) then failwith "contains: given invalid queue";
  let rec loop (value: 'a) (qn: 'a qnode option) : bool = 
    begin match qn with 
    | None -> false
    | Some h -> if v == value then true 
                else loop value h.next
    end
  in loop v q.head
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try your code it doesn't behave as you describe:

```
# let n = { v = 1; next = None };;
val n : int qnode = {v = 1; next = None}
# let q = { head = Some n; tail = Some n };;
val q : int queue =
  {head = Some {v = 1; next = None}; tail = Some {v = 1; next = None}}
# contains 3 q;;
- : bool = true
```

So, I'd say the answer depends on what `from_list` is actually returning.

As a side comment, your definition of `contains` has a reference to `elt`, which isn't defined anywhere that I can see.

**Update**

Your new code doesn't define `create`. I supplied this definition for `create`:

```
let create () = { head = None; tail = None }
```

If I run `from_list [1;2]`, this is what I see:

```
# from_list [1;2];;
- : int queue = {head = None; tail = None}
```

This would explain why the head appears to be `None` :-)

Comment: I'll update the post with the contents of `from_list`.  The `contains` function doesn't use the `elt` value because of my dumb re-writing.  I'll also post what my original code for `contains` was.

Comment: The function `from_list` appears to return an empty queue when passed a list of length 2.